# Change the style of multiple paragraphs on the page

Tags: javascript

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("button").length;
    for(var i=0;i<x;i++){
        document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
            document.querySelector("p").style.color="red";

        
        })
    }
```

This only changes the color of the first paragraph. I have also tried using querySelectorAll inside the anonymous function. please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion:

```js
btn.onclick = () => document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(p => p.style.color = "red");
```

```html
<p>Paragraph #1</p>
<p>Paragraph #2</p>
<p>Paragraph #3</p>

<button id="btn">Change All!</button>
```

Alternatively:

```js
var parr = document.querySelectorAll("p");
btn.onclick = () => {
  for (var p of parr) p.style.color = "red"
};
```

```html
<p>Paragraph #1</p>
<p>Paragraph #2</p>
<p>Paragraph #3</p>

<button id="btn">Change All!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to query all "p" and loop over them to apply the style. Just like your a doing on the buttons.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(paragraph => {
  paragraph.style.color="red";
})
```

Also, you might want to look into CSS variable which could help you to build it nicely (this is a bit out scope for this question).

You could to improve the title of your question's title to make it clear and more friendly.

Answer (score 0):

- You should not need to first select buttons. Select paragraphs directly.
- Use forEach to access array elements concisely

```js
let paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll("p")
paragraphs.forEach(elt => elt.style.color = "red" )
```